# typescript - default value of a class instance

Tags: typescript, syntax

I was wondering if this feature exists in Typescript:

If I had a class

```js
class Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
}
```

and I wanted it to return some default value when the instance is called

```
const person = new Person('Jim', 28)
console.log(person)
//> Jim
```

How would I achieve returning a custom/default value if the instance is called without accessing its properties or methods? Is there a keyword that could make a property act this way? I might imagine a 'default' keyword, but is there something similar?

```js
class Person {
  default name: string
  age: number
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is to override the `toString` and/or `valueOf` methods that are inherited from `Object.prototype`. **But**: `console.log` doesn't use those in most implementations, you'd have to do `console.log(String(person))` or similar.

For instance, `toString`:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  toString(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Live Example (JavaScript, [TypeScript version on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWjTAFt4AuaCAF0QEs0BzAbjwLAfMIFdiAjJFvmjB01RF2BUUiABRFSFMfQYAaaO05oe-RAEosrAtCoALWhAB08+NAC8hEvEFHjZyxrvqOz6AF9DUgDKNMoyuoohjAZCBIjwVFyIGKbmVo4+-riZImjU0AAOSKgY9mjwAO5wRegyAOQAUrTEtWoATAAcuoI5qCDwFiAoDDLBdIwyhcjoul1AA)):

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
  toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
const person = new Person('Jim', 28);
console.log(String(person));
```

Similarly, if you override `valueOf` and return a number, then when a numeric operator is used with your instance, it'll use the number `valueOf` returns:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.age;
  }
}
const person = new Person('Jim', 28);
console.log(person + 4); // 32
```

`valueOf` can return anything (including a string), although if it returns a non-primitive, that object will be converted to a primitive in the usual way for that object.

---

Side note: You can save yourself some typing by using TypeScript's automatic property declaration:

```
class Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
  }
  toString(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

The `public` in the parameter list to the constructor tells TypeScript to create those as public properties and to assign them within the code of the constructor for you.

Comment: This is good. If I wanted to do `'hello ' + person` then I'd get `> hello Jim`, which is the kind of behaviour I want - thanks.